# How do I search within 1 year of a date of birth within the query shown here (SQL)?

Tags: sql, date, intervals

I need to display some output data but within that data also search for a date of birth within a year of that date of birth in case of data entry issues.

This is my current code:

```
select  c.clientid [Client Id],c.nnn [NHS Number],c.surname 
Surname,c.firstname FirstName,c.gender Gender,c.dateofbirth [Date of 
Birth],c.dateregistered [Date Registered], ca.Postcode
from dbo.Client c 
inner join dbo.Client d 
on c.Surnamesoundex=d.Surnamesoundex and c.clientid<>d.clientid 
and (c.nnn is null or d.nnn is null)
and c.Firstnamesoundex=d.Firstnamesoundex 
and (c.clientid <> 1120198 and c.clientid <>1126429)
and  c.dateofbirth between c.DateOfBirth + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
left outer join dbo.clientaddress ca 
on d.clientid=ca.clientid and ca.todate is null 
order by c.SurnameSoundex,c.FirstnameSoundex
```

Im using an old version on SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting an error

Put quotes around the interval

```
 INTERVAL '1' YEAR
```

And also **between** should refer to a range

```
between ... and c.DateOfBirth + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
```

But it doesn't make sense to compare `c.dateofbirth` to itself.

You probably wanted -

```
c.dateofbirth between d.DateOfBirth and d.DateOfBirth + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
```

or -

```
d.dateofbirth between c.DateOfBirth and c.DateOfBirth + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
```

Comment: I get this error...

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near '1'.

And by 1, it means the number 1 next to INTERVAL

Comment: @DavidJeffery, you still didn't add a tag indicating your database (including version). Please add the updated query you're trying to run to your original post